# how can i install Intel Hd4000 and Amd radeon 7600 graphics driver?

Tags: 14.04, ati, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. But I can not configure my Intel HD 4000 and AMD Radeon 7670 graphics card. What I need to do to install them?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to this even if it is 13.10, I think it still applies [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455181/amd-radeon-hd-7500m-7600m-series-driver-for-ubuntu-13-10)